# Google+ posting comments

Tags: google-plus

I may completely misunderstand a subject, i don't use Google+ myself, so sorry if a question is a crap.
I spent 2 days trying to post a comment to google plus post via different API's. No success. My question is - is it possible? I can list posts, peoples, comments, but have no success in posting any kind of activity. I write comment using [moments.insert](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert), i receive success response from google, i can see this posted activity in my g+ account's "Apps and activities" section but nothing appears on web. Post still has 0 comments.
Can anybody point me to example that posts comments to g+? I am developing ios app, but platform and library of example don't actually matter, i just want to see this working. Also, if this is possible only through [Pages API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/pages-signup) this answer would be also greatly appreciated.
Thanks for attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `moments.insert` method is used to create an "app activity", not a post. This activity can be seen on the users profile if a person is permitted to see it (and if you know where to look - it isn't all that obvious), and the user may wish to post it to the stream once it is there, but it is never posted directly to the stream.

In fact, the general rule of thumb is that nothing can be posted directly to the stream without the user giving explicit approval to do so. There are, however, other ways to do this and still let the user "approve" the post. The most flexible way to do so is to use [sharing with interactive posts](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/) (the link is to the iOS information, but there are similar ways to do the same thing for other platforms).

The Pages API (if you can get approval) or using something like HootSuite is an exception to the rule, since they allow posts to be made without explicit user action. The [Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/) also allows this under some very limited and restricted circumstances (that you are posting only within an Apps Domain).